# Can bonding two NIC give me double speed on LAN?

Tags: download-speed, sockets, nic, network-bonding

I have three PC, named A, B, S. A have one NIC 100 Mb/s,  B is like A.  S have two NIC, each one is 100 Mb/s. I use a 1 Gbs switch. All NICs of A, B, S are connected to switch. Now a write a tool in Java to send data from A and B to S. S have a multithread server, it will open a new thread when a new client connected to it. I read the total data in a time and devide by the time to get the speed.

[image: My network]

I tried to bond two NIC in S in mode 0 and mode 4 803.2ad. But the receive speed at S is always near to 100, not 200 Mbps. Is the bonding can give me 200 Mbps download in S?

Comment: Did you test the speed before bonding?

Comment: Yes. Its around 88 to 100 Mbps.

Comment: Over Ethernet you should definitely be getting an aggregated throughput that is near to the sum of the individual interfaces. This is most likely a configuration problem - it would be helpful to see your /etc/network/interfaces and the output from $ cat /proc/bonding/net/bond0 Are you certain that both interfaces are actually being used to send data? It sounds like you've only got one interface being used. Try a packet sniffer like Wireshar, or a simple monitoring tool like ifstat, on all slave interface and try to ascertain whether data traffic is actually being sent through all slaves.

Answer (score 0):

Gmorning, i know this is a older thread but might be found by others also...

- I aGree with MDilmore that in case you setup bonding you will gain more Speed.

The other option would be:

S has 2 Nics and you have 2 IP's
Sofar we can you 2 Nics with 2 IP's with each seperate IP to get in touch with the Clients. Might not be usefull at all but it works also to transfer 200mbit through your 100mbit Switch

---

```
For Example:
 - S1: 192.168.2.20
 - S2: 192.168.2.30


 - A contact S1 100mbit
 - B contact S2 100mbit
```

Each Contact has seperated full 100mbit.